# Why does VSCode Remote-SSH keep asking for password and forgetting opened folders?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm using VSCode on Mac to connect to remote Windows computers using SSH (Remote-SSH) for developing Powershell scripts.
It works OK, except I have to type password 3 times:

- When connecting to the host
- After connecting in 5 seconds when the statusbar says "Adding extensions"
- After I click "Open folder"(VSCode doesn't remember the folders I previously added, I have to browse to them every time).
- A lot of times it asks for a password another time, after you open the folder and previous tabs, and start working with the code. If you miss the fact that it was asking for a password (which is easy - it's a small strip on the top of the window where you don't normally look while working with the code or if you Alt-Tab to a different app) - you have to relogin, resetting all opened tabs and losing changes.

I'm using this VSCode installation to debug Powershell scripts on Windows machines in different domains. I connect to VPNs of different clients many times a day, and doing that routine every time you want to change a line of code - is unbelievably inefficient.

ATTENTION: Please don't recommend RSA-keys authentication.
It breaks outbound authentication (https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/SSH-remote-sessions-on-Windows), which is used to authenticating as the Windows user that the script is launched as - connecting to network shares, launching remote commands on ADComputers, etc.

I would like to see: Password authentication that asks me for password 1 time, or none at all (i.e. password is stored in some kind of a keychain or a file).